# MouseLeftButtonDown event on InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas

Hi I have no ide why it isn't work. It looks like I can't use this event on InkCanvas.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="PolyLine.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel >
    <Button Name="Button1">Clear</Button>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="MC" MouseLeftButtonDown="MC_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseRightButtonDown="MC_MouseRightButtonDown" MouseMove="MC_MouseMove" Background="White"  Height="300" Width="497" ></InkCanvas>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind

```
private void MC_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    polylinePoints.Add(e.GetPosition(MC));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the topmost element? You can add Canvas.ZIndex="1000" (or another suitably big number) to force it to the front.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the InkCanvas handles the MouseLeftButtonDown event internally to initiate the drawing of an ink stroke. You could instead use the [PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseleftbuttondown.aspx) event, but you should be careful with what you do. In an InkCanvas a user would usually expect to start drawing a stroke when he presses the left mouse button.